# External Class is not autoloaded in symfony2.0 project

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.0

I want to add **EasyCSV** to my symfony2 project https://github.com/jwage/EasyCSV

This is what I tried. I added

```
'EasyCSV'          => __DIR__.'/../vendor/easy-csv',
```

to autoload.php and

```
use EasyCSV\Reader;
```

in my controller where I want to use this lib. But I get

> Fatal error: Class 'EasyCSV\Reader' not found in ...Controller.php

Any ideas why? How to fix this?

Comment: Does not change anything

Comment: Make sure you're adding that line to autoload.php under `registerNamespaces` and add `/lib` after `easy-csv`.

Comment: You mean like this '\EasyCSV'          => __DIR__.'/../vendor/easy-csv/lib', ?

Comment: Ignore my first comment. Don't add that extra \ at the beginning. Just add the `lib` and it should work. At least it did when I tested it on a fresh install

Comment: Were you able to try what I suggested?

Comment: Yes, the problem remains. I try to upgrade to sf 2.1, maybe that helps

Comment: So you have `'EasyCSV'          => __DIR__.'/../vendor/easy-csv/lib',` under `registerNamespaces`? I don't think it's a symfony version problem. Look in your vendor directory. What's the name of your easycsv folder?

Comment: under vendor I have a easy-csv folder, with 4 classes, thats all. each class has namespace "EasyCSV"

Comment: So your dir structure is something like `/vendor/easy-csv/Reader.php`? Can you paste your `deps` file?

Comment: http://dpaste.org/o6E3e/ I dont have it in deps file. But yes this is the exact structure

Comment: That's your problem then. You shouldn't put things manually in the vendor dir. Remove the current easy-csv dir and add `[easy-csv]
    git=http://github.com/jwage/EasyCSV.git` to your `deps` file. Then run the `php bin/vendors install` command and what I've outlined above should work.

Comment: Great thank you, it works now. Please post this as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we discussed in the comments, make sure that you don't manually add third party libraries to your vendors file. The built-in symfony package management system is there for a reason.

For the bundle in question, you should add the following to your `deps` file.

```
[easy-csv]
    git=http://github.com/jwage/EasyCSV.git
```

Then, you should add the following to your `app/autoload.php`

```
$loader->registerNamespaces(array(
    ...
    'EasyCSV'          => __DIR__.'/../vendor/easy-csv/lib',
));
```

Now you should be able to import the namespace and use it.

Answer (score 4):

Into `vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php` (Symfony 2.1)

```
<?php

// autoload_classmap.php generated by Composer

$vendorDir = dirname(__DIR__);
$baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);

return array(
    'EasyCSV' => __DIR__.'/../vendor/easy-csv',
    [....]
);
```

and then you can use it simply by insert

```
use EasyCSV
```

"at the top" of the file where you need it.

## **Without composer solution**

Try this into your `autoload.php` file (at the bottom, I suppose)

```
use Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\MapClassLoader;
[...]
// Create map autoloader
$mapLoader = new MapClassLoader(array(
    'EasyCSV' => __DIR__.'/../vendor/easy-csv',
    [...]
));

// Register autoloader
$mapLoader->register();
```

Comment: sorry, I did not mention that I use symfony2.0 without composer

Comment: @artworkad this doesn't "open any mind-drawer" to me... The only thing that I can remember about (since I've used symfony2.0 only for couple of months) is that you haven't to register your external file into ClassLoader but into ClassMap (as my composer-based answer hints). Could you do a grep of your files and search for "ClassLoader" or something like that?

Comment: It finds only doctrine ClassLoader, and the easy csv lib has its own class loader too https://github.com/jwage/EasyCSV/tree/master/lib/EasyCSV

Comment: Fatal error: Class 'Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\MapClassLoader' not found

Comment: @artworkad: you have to "import" it (use keyword). See my update

Comment: I know, I have this in autoload.php, however I get this error. Very strange

Comment: @artworkad: try to find that file into framework; I suppose that it is in there, but never say never

Comment: Yes it is there, I use netbeans as ide and when I command+click on it the ide opens the correct file

Comment: @artworkad: this is very strange to me; I've just try with a "plain" symfony2.0 installation and all works fine for me :|